# Laravel define multiple foregin key in models and getting error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

for this migration as:

```
Schema::create('user_tickets', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('subject');
    $table->integer('ticket_number')->unique();
    $table->tinyInteger('priority')->default(2);
    $table->tinyInteger('section');
    $table->boolean('solved')->default(false);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

and

```
Schema::create('user_tickets_answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->integer('ticket_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('ticket_id')->references('id')->on('user_tickets')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->text('reply',200);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

laravel create this foreign keys for me

```
user_tickets_answers_user_id_foreign
user_tickets_answers_ticket_id_foreign
```

on `user_tickets_answers` table, now when i try to get `user_tickets` data with `user_tickets_answers` relation such as:

```
$tickets = UserTickets::with('reply')->get();
```

i get this error:

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'diabet.user_ticket_answers' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `user_ticket_answers` where `user_ticket_answers`.`ticket_id` in (1))
```

how can i define this foreign keys on self models?

UserTickets :

```
class UserTickets extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function reply()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserTicketAnswers::class, 'ticket_id');
    }
}
```

UserTicketAnswers :

```
class UserTicketAnswers extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function ticket()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(UserTickets::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table name is different in migration it is **user_tickets_answers** while you are querying **user_ticket_answers** table in database.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the statements if it works, because it works for me when I had this error previously. To be sure, check again the [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) in passing custom key like

> ('App\Phone', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');

In UserTickets model change

```
return $this->hasMany(UserTicketAnswers::class, 'ticket_id');
```

to

```
return $this->hasMany('App\UserTicketAnswers','ticket_id','id');
```

In UserTicketAnswers

```
return $this->belongsTo(UserTickets::class);
```

to

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\UserTickets','ticket_id','ticket_id');
```

same logic with your `User` model.

```
public function userTickets(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserTickets','user_id','id');
}

public function userTicketAnswers(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserTicketAnswers','user_id','id');
}
```

Add each to `UserTickets` and `UserTicketAnswers` model

```
public function user{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Users','user_id','user_id');
}
```